# how to convert a QuerySet to a set in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I have a query,
`name_phonenum = person.objects.value_list('first_name','phone_num')`
I want to convert the queryset to a set. Any idea how can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it over a `set(…)`:

```
set(person.objects.value_list('first_name','phone_num'))
```

But you can let the database do the work with the [**`.distinct(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
person.objects.value_list('first_name','phone_num').distinct()
```

this will minimize the bandwidth from the database to the application layer.

Comment: Thank you. Yup using the distinct would have method the queryset without the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
people = Person.objects.all()
people_list = []
for person in people:
    people_list.append([person.first_name, person.phone_num])

people_set = set(people_list)
```

Didn't test this in shell, but should work fine.

Edit: William is correct, and his answer is much better.

Comment: You can not make a set of lists since lists are mutable, you should work with tuples instead.

Comment: Whoops, you're right! And your answer is clearly the better answer. Thanks for pointing that out